# Route::resource binding creates plural attribute routes (i.e. projects/{projects})

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am trying to set up a `Route:resource` for Series.

- When I create individual get, post, patch and delete Routes it works as expected (e.g. `GET series/${serie}`).
- However when I use Route::resource it creates plural attributes (e.g. `GET series/${series}`).
- In the laracast that I am following it creates the singular (e.g. `GET projects/${project}`).

I can't figure out what I am missing.

**This works:**

```
Route::get('/series', 'SeriesController@index');
Route::get('/series/create', 'SeriesController@create');
Route::get('/series/{serie}', 'SeriesController@show');
Route::post('/series', 'SeriesController@store');
Route::get('/series/{serie}/edit', 'SeriesController@edit');
Route::patch('/series/{serie}', 'SeriesController@update');
Route::delete('/series/{serie}', 'SeriesController@destroy');
```

**The route list is:**

```
GET|HEAD | series                | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@index
POST     | series                | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@store
GET|HEAD | series/create         | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@create
GET|HEAD | series/{serie}        | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@show
PATCH    | series/{serie}        | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@update
DELETE   | series/{serie}        | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@destroy
GET|HEAD | series/{serie}/edit   | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@edit
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
Route::resource('series', 'SeriesController');
```

**and produces this route list:**

```
GET|HEAD | series                | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@index
POST     | series                | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@store
GET|HEAD | series/create         | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@create
GET|HEAD | series/{series}       | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@show
PATCH    | series/{series}       | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@update
DELETE   | series/{series}       | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@destroy
GET|HEAD | series/{series}/edit  | App\Http\Controllers\SeriesController@edit
```

Notice the plural form {series}. Why is this happening?

Comment: The word `series` is both singular and plural, so `serie` would be incorrect, I can't even find it in the dictionary. See [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23268/is-series-plural-or-singular) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=serie)

Comment: If you **really** want to have `serie` you can still change it though https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Series" is the plural as well as the singular of the word, therefore the routes Laravel is generating are perfectly fine.

If you have a look into Laravels pluralizer helper, you can even see that "series" is explicitely listed as uncountable: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Support/Pluralizer.php#L49

Comment: Thank you very much. I am aware 'series' is uncountable, but didn't expect the framework to be smart enough to known about this.  Thanks for sharing the link to the Pluralizer.